# JavaFX + MenuBar

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

Как поместить MenuBar в верху Scene, если у меня используется GridPane?

В Swing было все проще, setJMenuBar() и дело в шляпе

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему

Попробовал поставить на BorderPane - GridPane

Что получилось: http://pastebin.com/dtPzw6fi

Comment: всё верно, обычно используют BorderPane в данном случае. Правда, я не совсем понял зачем вы свой GridPane устанавливаете справа, а не по центру. `borderPane.setRight(gridPane)`, а не `borderPane.setCenter(gridPane)`

Comment: экспериментировал